# timestamp problem in changes - snowflake sql

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

By using snowflake in project I need to get data every time I activate some process. Data must be from particular time and with it helps changes mechanism. When I set timestamp in select statement like

```
SELECT * FROM SOME_TABLE changes(INFORMATION => APPEND_ONLY) AT (TIMESTAMP =>  to_timestamp(':lastTime'));
```

I get all info, but when I do something like that using IIF function (due to business-logic)

```
SELECT * FROM SOME_TABLE changes(INFORMATION => APPEND_ONLY) AT (TIMESTAMP =>  IFF(1 = 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, to_timestamp(':lastTime')));
```

I get an error: **SQL Error [708] [02000]: Future data is not yet available for table SOME_TABLE.**

Any ideas?

Comment: to help debug this I would check current_timestamp is valid via `AT (TIMESTAMP => CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)` and then check that IFF is valid via `AT (TIMESTAMP =>  IFF(1 = 0, to_timestamp(':lastTime'), to_timestamp(':lastTime')))`

Comment: I have tested with both above options and also via ```(TIMESTAMP => IFF(1 = 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))```, everything works fine, but for ```AT (TIMESTAMP => IFF(1 = 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, to_timestamp(':lastTime'))) ``` it comes to 'Future data is not yet available' error as previously

Answer (score 0):

Ok so following the [changes examples](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/changes.html):

```
create or replace table t1 (
   id number(8) not null,
   c1 varchar(255) default null
);
 
alter table t1 set change_tracking = true;
 
set ts1 = (select current_timestamp());
  
insert into t1 (id,c1)
 values
 (1,'red'),
 (2,'blue'),
 (3,'green');
 
delete from t1 where id = 1;

update t1 set c1 = 'purple' where id = 2;
 
select *
from t1
   changes(information => append_only)
   at(timestamp => $ts1);
```

and it all worked as I expected.

I then tested the IFF works as you stated, but you know, just proving each step:

```
select *
from t1
   changes(information => append_only)
   at(timestamp => IFF(1 = 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP));  
   
select *
from t1
   changes(information => append_only)
   at(timestamp => IFF(1 = 0, $ts1, $ts1));  

select *
from t1
   changes(information => append_only)
   at(timestamp => IFF(1 = 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, $ts1));
```

that was all happy. So then I made an intentionally "future timestamp"

```
set ts2 = (select dateadd(hour, 1, current_timestamp()));
```

and using that gives the same error:

```
select *
from t1
   changes(information => append_only)
   at(timestamp => $ts2);
```

> Future data is not yet available for table T1.

using the if form it still explodes:

```
select *
from t1
   changes(information => append_only)
   at(timestamp => IFF(1 = 0, $ts2, $ts2));
```

but if I put the future on the non-used half of the logic:

```
select *
from t1
   changes(information => append_only)
   at(timestamp => IFF(1 = 0, $ts2, $ts1));
```

it works as I would expect.

This all leads me to believe, your timestamp is "in the future".

as to why I am not sure, but I would be tempted to put a LEAST on it to protect the query..

BUT:

```
   at(timestamp => LEAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,$ts2));
```

gives an constant requirement error:

> argument TIMESTAMP to function AT needs to be constant, found 'LEAST('2022-06-20 22:58:21.566000000Z', $TS2)'

so maybe a nested IFF

```
   at(timestamp => IFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP<$ts2, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, $ts2));
```

wozers, that fail also:

> argument TIMESTAMP to function AT needs to be constant, found 'IFF('2022-06-20 22:59:50.568000000Z' < $TS2, '2022-06-20 22:59:50.568000000Z', $TS2)'

which means you will need to limit it is a prior statement.

```
set safe_ts = (select LEAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, $ts2)); 
select *
from t1
   changes(information => append_only)
   at(timestamp => $safe_ts);
```